# How to pass the a VolumeClaimTemplate through tkn CLI and use them when starting a Pipeline so it applies to a PipelineRun

Tags: command-line-interface, openshift, tekton, tekton-pipelines

Is there a way to pass the claim as **VolumeClaimTemplate** and then provide its values to the pipeline so those are used when the PipelineRun is created at the execution of the pipeline instead of a PVC?

I have this **VolumeClaimTemplate** (see the image) and need to pass its details through the *tkn start pipeline-name* CLI command:
[image: VolumeClaimTemplate]

My entire CLI command is as next:

```
tkn pipeline start run-tests-portal-with-report --showlog \
 -w name=shared-data,claimName=VolumeClaimTemplate,storageClassName=default-netapp-disk,accessModes=ReadWriteOnce,storage=1Gi,volumeMode=Filesystem \
 -w name=git-credentials,secret=gh-token \
 -p repo-url=https://github.com/my-project-url \
 -p revision=PRJT-123
```

Now this is the error I am getting in openshift:

> message: >-
> pod status "PodScheduled":"False"; message: "0/12 nodes are available:
> 12 persistentvolumeclaim "VolumeClaimTemplate" not found. preemption:
> 0/12 nodes are available: 12 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling."

I understand the issue, but how do I tell it through the CLI that 'use this **VolumeClaimTemplate**' where the '**StorageClass** is *default-netapp-disk*' with the other details (though when I manually select the storage class in the UI it automatically sets the access mode, size and volume mode) and then it'll use it to create the **PersistentVolume** at runtime within the PipelineRun?

I hope this is explanatory enough, **Is this even doable?**

I've tried many things and could not find a solution, I am not even sure this is doable.

Answer (score 0):

The command that you provided will create an incorrect workspace in the `PipelineRun` that looks like this:

```yaml
workspaces:
  - name: source
    persistantVolumeClaim:
      claimName: VolumeClaimTemplate
```

You need to use the `volumeClaimTemplateFile` option with the `—workspace` parameter when you use the `tkn` CLI like the following (https://github.com/tektoncd/cli/pull/1066):

```bash
tkn pipeline start pipeline-with-workspace --workspace name=myworkspace,volumeClaimTemplateFile=/path/to/pvc.yaml
```

Where `pvc.yaml` is the file that will be like that for your case:

```yaml
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  storageClassName: default-netapp-disk
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

By running the command the generated `PipelineRun` will be:

```yaml
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: PipelineRun
metadata:
  name: my-pipelinerun-name
spec:
  workspaces:
    - name: myworkspace
      volumeClaimTemplate:
        spec:
          accessModes:
            - ReadWriteOnce
          volumeMode: Filesystem
          storageClassName: default-netapp-disk
          resources:
            requests:
              storage: 1Gi    
pipelineRef:
    name: pipeline-with-workspace
```